# Configuring log4net appenders via XML file *and* code

Tags: log4net, appender, rollingfileappender, log4net-configuration

I started to play with log4net today and so far, I really like it.  In order to preserve our current logging functionality, the app needs to create a new log file whenever the application is started.  The log file name has the date and time stamp encoded in it.  Currently, I've got log4net configured via an `XmlConfigurator`, which works great, except that the filename for my `RollingFileAppender` is hardcoded in the configuration XML file.

I'd like to continue to use the `XmlConfigurator`, but after calling `Configure()`, I want to get at the `RollingFileAppender` and, in code, change its file value to be a dynamically-generated string.  The sample [documentation online](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/example-config-appender.html) seems to be down right now, but I've poked through the SDK reference, and it looks like I could use the `Heirarchy` and `GetAppenders()` to do what I need to do.  Am I on the right track?

Ok, I took a stab at this and tried the following code, which didn't work:

```cs
private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(GUI));
// in the config file, I've set the filename to example.log, and it works
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log_config.xml"));
Hierarchy hierarchy = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;
if(hierarchy != null) {
    // get the appenders
    IAppender[] appenders = hierarchy.GetAppenders();
    // change the filename for the RollingFileAppender
    foreach( IAppender a in appenders) {
        RollingFileAppender rfa = a as RollingFileAppender;
        if(rfa == null)
            continue;
        rfa.File = "newfile.log"; // no runtime error, but doesn't work.
    }
}
_log.Info("Application started");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you in this case need the rolling file appender? If not I would expect that your code would create the desired result if you used the normal file appender.

Edit: Maybe it works with the RollingFile Appender if you call `ActivateOptions()` on the appender.

Answer (score 8):

Try this snippet:

```cs
XmlConfigurator.Configure();

log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository repo = LogManager.GetRepository();
foreach (log4net.Appender.IAppender appender in repo.GetAppenders())
{
if (appender.Name.CompareTo("RollingFileAppender") == 0 && appender is log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender)
{
   var appndr = appender as log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender;
   string logPath = "MyApplication.log";
   appndr.File = logPath;
   appndr.ActivateOptions();
}
```

I had posted similar article [here](http://karpcom.blogspot.com/2010/04/initialising-log4net-logging-for-aspnet.html)

Comment: +1 for nicer implementation, except that your call to Configure needs to specify the XML file used for configuration.

Comment: @Dave: No it doesn't, a call to `Configure()` will use the `app.config` or `web.config` of the project in question.